# CSS Resize Table Has No Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize a table using CSS.  I can resize the width of the table fine, but resizing the height in CSS has no effect.  This is my HTML Code

```
<div id="header">
    <table id="header_wrap">
        <tr><td id="title_section"><span id="title" align="left">larder.</span>
        <h5 id="subtitle" align="left">Live Well. Spend Less.</h5></td>
        <td id="menu" align="right"><span align="right"><?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) { echo "welcome back, $username!"; } else {echo "";}?></span><span><a href="show.php"><br>Show Cupboard</a> </span><span>| <a href="protected_page.php">Home</a> </span><span>| About </span><span><?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) { echo "<a href='includes/logout.php'>| Log out"; } else {echo "<a href='index.php'>| Log in";}?></a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The object I'm trying to resize is 'header_wrap'

This is my CSS code:

```
#header_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Not sure why this is not working.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting a height on the body/html? Also, post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: I have tried and your code works fine with **HTML Only**. I have not worked with PHP but I guess you are making syntax mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

please correct your Syntax.

from the line code `</span><span><a href="show.php"><br>Show Cupboard</a> </span>`

remove `"<br>"`

and fix this line code `<a href='index.php'>| Log in";}?></a>`

you mix between php code and html code

Answer (score 0):

The **height** does work. 
If you add this code to your CSS and change the **height**:

```
 border: black 1px solid;
```